# Magento2.4: How to Reindex Programatically with a button?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.4

I want to **Re-Index programmatically** with a button. the button can be in system configuration or in a page, when clicking on that button it should re-index the Magento.

Comment: Not a good idea, unless your store is very little. Doing this as a web request will require to increase time & memory limits

Comment: client want a page where all cache and reindex will be done with a button

Comment: he wants button for these tasks

Comment: Yes, most clients want this. But sometimes our task is to educate clients more than just doing what they want 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> /Pyaray/Indexing/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="custom_indexing" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Custom Indexing</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="custom_indexing" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Indexing</label>
            <tab>custom_indexing</tab>
            <resource>Custom_Indexing::indexing</resource>
            <group id="custom_indexing" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Custom Indexing</label>
                <field id="custom_indexing" translate="label" type="button" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Manual Indexing</label>
                    <frontend_model>Pyaray\Indexing\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Button</frontend_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

> \Pyaray\Indexing\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Button.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Pyaray\Indexing\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

/**
 *
 */
class Button extends Field
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCustomUrl(): string
    {
        return $this->getUrl('indexing/indexing/indexing'); \\ this is the path to a controller, my controller and route frontName is "indexing"
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function getButtonHtml(): string
    {
        $button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button')->setData([
            'id' => 'custom_indexing',
            'label' => __('Indexing'),
        ]);
        return $button->toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return $this|Button
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        if (!$this->getTemplate()) {
            $this->setTemplate('system/config/fieldset/custom_button.phtml');
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param AbstractElement $element
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        return $this->_toHtml();
    }
}
```

> \Pyaray\Indexing\Controller\Adminhtml\Indexing\Indexing.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Pyaray\Indexing\Controller\Adminhtml\Indexing;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory;
use Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\Collection;

class Indexing extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var IndexerFactory
     */
    protected IndexerFactory $indexFactory;
    /**
     * @var ResultFactory
     */
    protected ResultFactory $resultRedirect;
    /**
     * @var Collection
     */
    protected Collection $indexCollection;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param IndexerFactory $indexFactory
     * @param ResultFactory $resultRedirect
     * @param Collection $indexCollection
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        IndexerFactory $indexFactory,
        ResultFactory $resultRedirect,
        Collection $indexCollection
    ) {
        $this->indexCollection = $indexCollection;
        $this->resultRedirect = $resultRedirect;
        $this->indexFactory = $indexFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute action based on request and return result
     *
     * @return ResultInterface
     * @throws NotFoundException
     */
    public function execute(): ResultInterface
    {
        $indexes = $this->indexCollection->getAllIds();
        foreach ($indexes as $index) {
            $indexFactory = $this->indexFactory->create()->load($index);
            $indexFactory->reindexAll($index);
            $indexFactory->reindexRow($index);
        }
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirect->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

> /Pyaray/Indexing/view/adminhtml/templates/system/config/fieldset/custom_button.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * @var \Pyaray\Indexing\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Button $block
 */
?>
<div class="pp-buttons-container">
    <p>
        <button
                onclick="setLocation('<?php  echo $block->getCustomUrl() ?>')"
                type="button">
            <?php  echo __('Indexing!') ?>
        </button>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-index from backend, please use mageplaza backend reindex module.

Also screen shot is attached on github repository.

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-backend-reindex

I hope it will helpful to you.

Thank you.